# Skipping cells that are coloured

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop, where I want to skip cells that are coloured.

```
For i = 1 To Count
    Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
        i = i + 1: Count = Count + 1
    Loop

    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
Next i
```

It works, however the initial count variable is not updated. Thus, if I have `10` and there are `2` skips, the `i` value is increased and that works, still the `count` remains at `10`, even though the variable says `12`. It appears as though increasing the `count` variable does not increment the `For` loop. I cannot take `1` away from the `i` variable because that leads to the `activecell.offset` being impacted.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you are trying to find the last cell that has a color index of 15 and then changing the color of the next cell?

Comment: A for loop is precompiled you can't alter it after you start it. You need to use a While loop to be able to increment count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change length of For loop while in the loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409644/change-length-of-for-loop-while-in-the-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use `.Offset` at all? Is this what you are trying? This way you can skip the colored cells as well.

```
Dim col As Long, rw As Long, i As Long

col = ActiveCell.Column
rw = ActiveCell.Row

For i = 1 To Count
    With Cells(rw, col + i)
        If .Interior.ColorIndex <> 15 Then
            With .Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
                .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Siddhart, as usual you provide a great answer! The reason I had to keep the offset, if because there can be a remainder, which needs to be in a different colour. In essence, I am creating a planner which takes numbers and divides them by 7.5 (a working day) and then paints by offset by the answer from the division, while the remainder will be tinted a different colour. See below for my convoluted answer.

Comment: I am sure, you still do not need the `.Offset` :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably very inefficient code, but there are not a lot of rows. Remember the idea is that the column has a date, if that column is Saturday or Sunday, i.e., coloured grey, then the code should skip those cells and but not subtract them from the overall counter.

```
If Not IsEmpty(y.Value) And IsNumeric(y.Value) And y.Value >= 7.5 Then
With ActiveCell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Col = y.Value - 7.5
Col = Col / 7.5


Count = Left(Col, Len(Col) - InStr(1, Col, ".") + 1)
y = 0
For i = 1 To Count


Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
y = y + 1
Loop
With ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Next i

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -y).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, i + y).Select
Do While ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
Co = Right(Col, Len(Col) - InStr(1, Col, "."))
If Len(Co) > 2 Then
Co = Mid(Co, 1, InStr(1, Col, ".")) & "." & Mid(Co, InStr(1, Col, ".") + 1, Len(Co) - InStr(1, Col, "."))
End If
If Co = 0 Then
ElseIf Co >= 0.1 And Co <= 25 Then
With ActiveCell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Co >= 26 And Co <= 49 Then
With ActiveCell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Co >= 5 And Co <= 74 Then
With ActiveCell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ElseIf Co >= 75 And Co <= 99 Then
With ActiveCell.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -4.99893185216834E-02
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
End If
End If

Next y
```